# What are the travel scenarios that include walking?

Tags: sightseeing, nature-and-wildlife, hiking

I have been walking the [Way of st. James](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Way_of_St._James) and it is a great mixture of seeing good architecture, experiencing the culture, meeting people, sleeping in cheap accommodation, spending times in the nature, walking, and generally having fun. I have found this way of traveling (walking + a lot of extra) very appealing because just hiking itself can be sometimes very mundane. I would like to know if there are any other travel scenarios that include walking in an unique atmosphere, similar to the one I described. I am merely not asking about ordinary walking trails as there are dozens of them out there.

Comment: could you elaborate, or be more specific in terms of countries? There are thousands of roads and hundreds of countries - as it stands, this question is still very broad.

Comment: What Mark said. At the moment this question is too vague, please do edit and then flag for reopening; perhaps clarify what to you mean by 'a lot extra' and where. List-style, open-ended, vague questions are generally not allowed on StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what it is you are looking for but you can simply look at [old pilgrim routes](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=old%20pilgrimage%20routes&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&fp=431d504f5f1958f8&ix=seb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1024&bih=656)

Of which there are plenty.  There are specific [pilgrimage holidays](http://www.pilgrimroutes.com/), which for some reason doesn't include Israel, but I'm not complaining.